# Mysterious margin once again

Tags: html, css

Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/iDtR5cV6

My problem is the 12px space appearing seemingly out of nowhere, between Main and Footer. I think I've added `{margin:0; padding:0;}` wherever necessary, but I guess I need another pair of eyes to look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a default top and bottom margin on the `p` element in your footer causing that space. Setting `footer p { margin-top: 0; }` will remove that space.

Comment: @Alan np! btw, learning to use the dev tools in your browser, you can figure these kinds of issues out on your own really quickly.